# Data & email message from html form not appearing after received in admin email, but attachment appears and works fine

Tags: php, email

Please i really need help! I created an html form, when submitted, it goes to admin email. My problem is attachment appears fine in received email, but the message body is blank, not appearing. What am i not getting right? This is my php code below.

```
<?php
//get data from form  

$name= $_POST['name'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$jobrole= $_POST['jobrole'];
$portfoliowebsite = $_POST['portfoliowebsite'];
$address= $_POST['address'];
$city= $_POST['city'];
$tel= $_POST['phone'];
$fileName = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
$filenameee = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
$date= $_POST['date'];
$msg= $_POST['coverletter'];

$message ="Name: ". $name . "\r\n  Email: " . $email . "\r\n  Job Applied For: " . $jobrole . "\r\n  Portfolio Website: " . $portfoliowebsite . "\r\n  Contact Address: " . $address . "\r\n  City: " . $city . "\r\n  Phone: " . $tel . "\r\n  Date: " . $date . "\r\n Coverletter: " . $msg;


$subject = "Job Application";
$fromname ="Goldengroup";
$fromemail = 'noreply@goldengroup.com';  //if u dont have an email create one on your cpanel

$mailto = "r.ralph@goldengroup.com";


    $content = file_get_contents($fileName);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    // a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
    $separator = md5(time());
    // carriage return type (RFC)
    $eol = "\r\n";
    // main header (multipart mandatory)
    $headers = "From: ".$fromname." <".$fromemail.">" . $eol;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
    $headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol;
    
    
    // message
    $body = "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol;
    $body .= $message . $eol;
    
    // attachment
    $body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filenameee . "\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filenameee."\"" . $eol . $eol; "size=" . filesize ($uploadedFile) ."";
    $body .= $content . $eol;
    $body .= "--" . $separator . "--";

   
   if($email!=NULL){
    mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers);
}
//redirect
header("Location:thankyou.html");

?>
```

I've tried the code above, attachment works fine, but message body not appearing in received email

Answer (score 1):

1. You are missing `$eol` in a number of places in your `$body`
2. Please properly read the file content, such as using

```
    
    $file3 = $fileName;
    $file_size3 = filesize($file3);
    $handle3 = fopen($file3, "r");
    $content3 = fread($handle3, $file_size3);
    fclose($handle3);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content3));
```

3. This line is redundant (the one after `Content-Type: multipart/mixed;`), so let's remove / remark it

```
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" .
```

4. Better use `md5(uniqid(time()));` instead of  `md5(time());` as the separator

So, please change the following part

```
    $content = file_get_contents($fileName);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    // a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
    $separator = md5(time());
    // carriage return type (RFC)
    $eol = "\r\n";
    // main header (multipart mandatory)
    $headers = "From: ".$fromname." <".$fromemail.">" . $eol;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
    $headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol;
    
    
    // message
    $body = "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol;
    $body .= $message . $eol;
    
    // attachment
    $body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filenameee . "\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filenameee."\"" . $eol . $eol; "size=" . filesize ($uploadedFile) ."";
    $body .= $content . $eol;
    $body .= "--" . $separator . "--";

   
   if($email!=NULL){
    mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers);
}


?>
```

to the following **(tested - 100% work)**

```
   
    $file3 = $fileName;
    $file_size3 = filesize($file3);
    $handle3 = fopen($file3, "r");
    $content3 = fread($handle3, $file_size3);
    fclose($handle3);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content3));

//  $separator = md5(time());
    $separator = md5(uniqid(time()));

    // carriage return type (RFC)
    $eol = "\r\n";
    // main header (multipart mandatory)
    $headers = "From: ".$fromname." <".$fromemail.">" . $eol;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;" . $eol . " boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" ;
  //  $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
    $headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol. $eol;
    
    // message
    $body = "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol. $eol;
    $body .= $message . $eol;
    
    // attachment
    $body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream;". $eol . " name=\"" . $filenameee . "\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;". $eol . " filename=\"" . $filenameee."\"" . $eol . $eol ; 
    $body .= $content . $eol;
    $body .= "--" . $separator . "--";
   
    mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: Bravo! bravo! bravo! thank you. You are really amazing. It worked